# How to create custom strongly typed HtmlHelper?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper, htmlextensions

For example when using a

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(v => Model.Text);
```

and submitting the form, the value in the TextBox is automatically assigned to `Model.Text`.

I want to write such a custom HTML helper.

I know how to write such a extension method for displaying HTML, but how to program the behaviour to assign the value `Model.WhatEver`.

I want to build a Tag-Cloud and I think it is a good idea to include it in a way like:

```
@Html.TagCloud(v => Model.SelectedTags, Model.AvailableTags)
```

The HTML-Helper just prints out HTML, but how can I assign values to `Model.SelectedTags`?

Comment: Think: What's v? Why would it be there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See how this method is defined:

```
public static MvcHtmlString TextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression);
```

It is just generic extension method in static class returning `MvcHtmlString`. Just write one yourself and insert it into view via web.config.

```
<pages>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="NameSpaceWithYourClass" />
```

Remeber that this method have to take `this HtmlHelper<TModel>` as extension parameter and
`Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression` as expression for selecting property and you will be fine.

BTW: i think for your need would be better partial view since HTML for it can be quite complicated.